# Can a USA president pardon him/her self?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

I saw an [article](http://mobile.abc.net.au/news/2018-06-05/donald-trump-says-he-has-absolute-right-to-pardon-himself/9834788?pfmredir=sm&sf191046451=1) where Donald Trump is claiming he can pardon himself.  Is this actually possible?

http://mobile.abc.net.au/news/2018-06-05/donald-trump-says-he-has-absolute-right-to-pardon-himself/9834788?pfmredir=sm&sf191046451=1

Answer (score 0):

No president has ever tried it, so the question has not been settled.